# Migration "our target project 'xxx' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'xxx'" using aspnet Core 1.0 RC2 -

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core-rc2

I'm trying to build the migration classes for a second DBContext in a assembly. using this command: `Add-Migration AlertInitial -c Axper.Data.Persistence.Context.AlertContext` 
and using the "Package Console management"

But it fail and give me this error:

> Your target project 'AxPortal' doesn't match your migrations assembly
>   'Axper.Data.Persistence'.  Either change your target project or change
>   your migrations assembly. Change your migrations assembly by using
>   DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b =>
>   b.MigrationsAssembly("AxPortal")).  By default, the migrations
>   assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.
>
> Change your target project to the migrations project by using the
>   Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by
>   executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations
>   project.

I can't figure what this error mean, and what to do to fix it.
Can someone help?

Comment: I like to but the project that hold the migration class, is a Class Library. And since RC2, Class Library isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For unknown reason, my projects/Solution folder was kind of corrupted. I deleted I and re-cloned the Git Repository. I i finally been able to do the migration.

Comment: This was my problem. To be sure I closed the solution, deleted the .vs, bin and obj folders and then re-opened the solution. The problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

> options.UseSqlServer(connection, b =>
>   b.MigrationsAssembly("WebApplication3")). By default, the migrations
>   assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.

```
services.AddDbContext<ComDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer("server=.\\sqlexpress;database=dsafdsaf;uid=sa;pwd=123456", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("WebApplication3"));
            });
```